# UseCallback and useMemo guarantee to return the same value when their dependencies do not change?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

> You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee. In the future, React may choose to “forget” some previously memoized values and recalculate them on next render, e.g. to free memory for offscreen components. Write your code so that it still works without useMemo — and then add it to optimize performance. This is the original sentence from the [**legacy** React documentation](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo), and

I can understand a half. Actually I rarely use `useMemo`, I know it means useMemo can't guarantee to return the same value even if it's dependencies do not change. But when I open the [new React documentation](https://react.dev/), there are similar sentence in the page of [useMemo](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo) and [useCallback](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback)

> React will not throw away the cached value/function unless there is a specific reason to do that. For example, in development, React throws away the cache when you edit the file of your component. Both in development and in production, React will throw away the cache if your component suspends during the initial mount. In the future, React may add more features that take advantage of throwing away the cache—for example, if React adds built-in support for virtualized lists in the future, it would make sense to throw away the cache for items that scroll out of the virtualized table viewport. This should match your expectations if you rely on useMemo/useCallback as a performance optimization. Otherwise, a state variable or a ref may be more appropriate.

It really confuses me. I can't imagine living without a guarantee that useCallback never changes. Firstly, the React docs tell me that I can use useCallback to wrap functions executed in useEffect but defined outside. This way, we can reduce the number of dependencies. When I use a function returned by a hook from myself or a third-party library in useEffect, I think the functions were wrapped by useCallback, so I can put them in the dependencies array as Eslint tells me to do. If they quietly change, some extra queries may happen, which could bring my table back to page 1 again. Maybe I can avoid abusing useCallback, but what about those third-party libraries?

**I think actually my App rely on useEffect**, which makes me nervous and confused, or I just understand incorrectly?

I think it is not a proper example, but I can only think it now.

```js
const Table = memo(() => {
  // a function can be used to get the message popup
  const [value, setValue] = useState({});
  const { message } = useMessage();

  useEffect(() => {
    // if id change, it should query the data from page1
    request({ page: 1, id }).then((res) => {
      setValue(res.data);
      message("success");
    });
    // if function message change, it will query the data in page1 accidently
  }, [message, id]);
});
```

Comment: Please remove one of the 2 redundant paragraphs (starting with "It really confuses me...")

Answer (score 0):

#### Optimization

You should think of [`useMemo`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo) and [`useCallback`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback) [only as *optimizations*](https://useMemo%20as%20a%20performance%20optimization).

That means:
Imagine you would just *not* use `useMemo` or `useCallback` at all, then your code should run just fine, only less performant. Then you add `useMemo` or `useCallback`, and you code runs *more* performant, but there still might be redundant calls of your functions.

#### Think of state, not call-order

In React, you should [describe you UI "declaratively", not modify it "imperatively".](https://react.dev/learn/reacting-to-input-with-state#how-declarative-ui-compares-to-imperative).

That means you should think about state and depending state, you should *not* think about when or in which order things happen. The term *"dependencies"* is chosen on purpose: They only tell React on what other state a state depends on.

#### Effects vs. events

So, if you page **depends on some external data**, i.e. needs to fetch some data to display, you can do that inside a `useEffect` and cancel it or discard or ignore the result inside the cleanup function, but it should be ok to call that effect multiple times.

If the `fetch` really *must not* happen more than once, it is likely that it's actually **not dependent on some state**, but the (possibly indirect) **consequence of an event**, like a mouse click. Then you should not use `useEffect`, but arrange your app so that the `fetch` is called by the event hanlder (directly or indirectly).

In fact, React recommends to [use `useEffect` as a last resort](https://react.dev/learn/keeping-components-pure#where-you-_can_-cause-side-effects):

> If you’ve exhausted all other options and can’t find the right event handler for your side effect, you can still attach it to your returned JSX with a useEffect call in your component. This tells React to execute it later, after rendering, when side effects are allowed. However, this approach should be your last resort.

Comment: Maybe my expression is ambiguous. I need to fetch the table data when I enter, and React suggest me putting function which exported by hooks in the deps array. The immute may depend on useCallback wrapper, and the request can't be cancelled, just get data. If useCallback may return different function, request maybe happen again, maybe bring bad effects, see my example in the question.
I just find another way, I can separate some functions which maybe change. It is ugly to me, and I just see many people code like me, they don't know the warning in the new docs  Is my understanding corrent?